# Network Driver advanced Properties through code

Tags: properties, driver

Trying to modify the advanced properties of a driver through code.  I can go to the device manager, and right click on a device driver, and see a "Advanced" tab.  On this tab is a property ("wireless mode"), that I want to change  (to change it from a/b mode to a/b/g/n mode).  I can do this by hand fairly easily, but I am unsure as to how to do this in code (need to run this automated on a remote system).

The closest I can come up with is using Win32 API to call SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty, which gets me a lot of info about the driver, but only the built in properties that windows expects.  I dont know how to get/modify the custom attrabutes that are shown in that advanced screen.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Think I found it, using the Win32 API given above, I got the driver GUID, and #.  Then going in HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\\<# of driver>.  Here I can set the value of the properties (looking for the property name as a key), and if I go under Ndi\params\NAME\enum, I can see all the possible values and the string representation of them.